# Using C++ AMP Library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, gpu, c++-amp

I'm trying to start playing around with the `<amp.h>` library. But when I type `#include amp.h`,  I get an error saying cannot open source file `<amp.h>`. Is there something special I need to do to make this available?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <amp.h>
```

Comment: I'd recommend switching best answer to Kate Gregory's answer.  It's better in my opinion.  Another bit of advice:  to figure out important bits of how most things work in Microsoft land, you have to read other developer's blog posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ AMP requires not only the amp.h header file, but a new compiler (in order to understand the restrict keyword, for example). The Developer Preview of VS 11 (either the one you can download onto a Windows 7 machine or the one that comes with the Developer Preview image of Windows 8) has the compiler you need. Your existing copy of VS 2010 (or whatever) does not. Getting the header file into your include path won't be enough. If you have the right compiler, you will discover that amp.h is on your include path already.

---

Check out [this April 2012 MSDN Magainze Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882446.aspx) for more info on C++ AMP

Comment: @PeterTurner that's an old article (but then again this is an old answer) - take a look at http://www.gregcons.com/cppamp/ - we have resources at the bottom and more resources on the codeplex page

Comment: Nice, should have checked your profile, didn't know I was editing the answer of the world's foremost expert :) (I haven't even read the whole MSDN article - I don't have Visual Studio [I'm a Delphi programmer], I just figured editing a good, but unreferenced, answer would be more appropriate than adding a throwaway comment)

Answer (score 0):

amp.h must not be available in your standard library include paths.

If this is a not-often-used header file, I'd add the library include files into your project and include them from there.

If not, I'd search for amp.h on your filesystem, try including it using `#include "amp.h"` and then add the path where it is to my library include paths on your VS project.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in my file path :( any idea where i can download it?

Comment: @atbyrd - Googling reveals that it might either be in DirectX SDK or an SDK bundled with VC++.  I'd try downloading those and then doing what my answer suggests.  If you aren't sure about how #include's work, I'd read the C++ FAQ Lite.  And if your'e new to C++ - good luck!  There be many dragons on your journey.